# String to double в java

Tags: java, строки, float, double

Имеется строка вида: `122.32,20.543`. Каким образом в  [java](/questions/tagged/java) распилить ее чтобы получить два double типа `double1 = 122.32` и `double2 = 20.543`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разделить по запятой и каждую подстроку преобразовать в double.

```
String[] tokens = "122.32,20.543".split(",");
Double double1 = Double.valueOf(tokens[0]);
Double double2 = Double.valueOf(tokens[1]);
```

Для решения достаточно посмотреть на документацию к классам String и Double.

Answer (score 1):

а я опять изобрел велосипед(((

```
    String s = "122.32,20.543";

    Double d1 = Double.valueOf(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(",")));
    Double d2 = Double.valueOf(s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1));

    System.out.println("Число 1 = "+d1 + "\nЧисло 2 = "+ d2);
```